# Why is PHP not seeing my query string?

Tags: php, parameters, query-string

This [phpinfo()](http://www.greengar.com/scores/info.php?qwerty=asdfg) demonstrates the problem.

I'm passing the URL a query string of:

```
?qwerty=asdfg
```

As a result, I'm expecting it to list these two PHP variables:

```
_REQUEST["qwerty"] asdfg
_GET["qwerty"] asdfg
```

And also this query string:

```
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] qwerty=asdfg
```

However, it's not working. None of these variables seem to be set at all.

I'm using lighttpd. This may or may not be related to the problem, but my greengar.com-lighttpd.conf looks like this, because I'm using WordPress for most of the domain's pages:

```
### Generated by Elliot
### Wordpress: http://www.greengar.com
url.rewrite += (
    "^/(wp-.+).*/?" => "$0",
    "^/(blog/wp-.+).*/?" => "$0",
    "^/(.*.php)" => "$0",
    "^/(.*.pdf)" => "$0",
    "^/(.*.png)" => "$0",
    "^/(.*.html)" => "$0",
    "^/(.*.ico)" => "$0",
    "^/(.*.gif)" => "$0",
    "^/(.*.txt)" => "$0",
    "^/(images).*/?" => "$0",
    "^/(sitemap.xml)" => "$0",
    "^/(xmlrpc.php)" => "$0",
    "^/(.+)/?$" => "/index.php/$1"
)
```

Again, I don't know for sure whether this is related to the problem.

My question is: why isn't PHP seeing the query string?

And how do I fix it?

Here's a normal [phpinfo()](http://www.greengarstudios.com/scores/info.php?qwerty=asdfg) which successfully sees the query string. This is running on a different server, which is running Apache.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ModRewrite

At the bottom:

"If you wanna pass the Query String (?foo=bar) to the rewrite destination you have to explicitly match it:"

And the alternative is to read it through $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: I spent a couple hours learning regexes so that I could confidently make the change that would match and pass along the query string. Here it is: "^/(.*.php)(\?(.*))?" => "$0", (replace line 6 of the code in my question)

Comment: RELATED: I was having this problem with Apache; turned out the RewriteBase line in .htaccess was messing it up: you can't say `RewriteBase /#comment`

Answer (score 0):

Just checking but it should be $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] - does your actual code include the $?

Comment: Yes, it does. I left out the $ in the question because phpinfo() leaves it out.