# NSURLConnection not sending querystring

Tags: php, cocoa-touch, mod-rewrite, query-string, nsurlconnection

**Update:** Thanks to Rob, I've discovered the server is also not seeing querystring parameters when simply typing the address into iOS Safari (Chrome Mac OS, however, works fine). So it appears it may be something strange on the server side after all.

---

I'm having a strange issue where the following code is not sending the querystring section of the request. If I log `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` on the server side, it is blank. However if I simply type the url into a browser, the server correctly logs it.

Also strangely `NSURL` picks up the query string fine if I log `[nsurl query]`, so the problem appears to be with either `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLRequest`.

```
NSString* queryString = [self.appDelegate.connections componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/?%@&isajax=1", queryString];
NSLog(@"url: %@", url); // http://mysite.com/?test&isajax=1

NSURL* nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSLog(@"nsurl: %@", [nsurl query]); // test&isajax=1

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^( NSURLResponse* response, NSData* responseData, NSError* error ) {
    // returns the page as if no query string were present at all
}];
```

I'm wondering if it has to do with the lack of a filename. Maybe `NSURLConnection` doesn't like that. **Edit:** Nope, nothing to do with that. Tried `/index.php?test&isajax=1` and still no good.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the request parameters, you should be accessing [`$_REQUEST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), not `$_SERVER`. Or, if it was a post query, you could use `$_POST`. But [`according to the documentation`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), `$_SERVER` returns the server headers:

> `$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations.

Whereas [`$_REQUEST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) returns an

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Thus, if your request was:

```
http://mysite.com/?test=abc&isajax=1
```

Then `$_REQUEST['test']` would return `abc` and `$_REQUEST['isajax']` would return `1`.

---

If you really want the un-parsed query string, you certainly can use `$_SERVER`. Thus consider the following PHP code:

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER('QUERY_STRING');

?>
```

And the following Objective-C code (which checks for `NSURLConnection` related errors):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/?test=abc&isajax=1"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
        return;
    }
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"result string: %@", string);
}];
```

That returns, as expected:

```
result string: test=abc&isajax=1
```

If you're not getting anything, you might want to turn on error logging in php, so you can see if you're getting any php errors, too. (For example, in your `php.ini` temporarily set `display_errors = On`.)

Comment: "...an array containing information **such as** headers..." The `'QUERY_STRING'` index is clearly documented.

Comment: Fwiw, `$_GET` is also blank for the expected query parameter. E.g. `$_GET["isajax"]`.

Comment: @chaiguy Sure, you can use `_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, too, if you want all of your parameters returned in a single string. I was assuming you were looking for a easy way to get all of the query parameters individually. But if you're going to parse that manually yourself, you can use `_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. For example, if I have a php page that does `<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>`, it returns the query string fine. Maybe you can modify your question showing your PHP code. But issuing a request, like you have, works fine (though I wouldn't use the `mainQueue`).

Comment: @chaiguy Are you sure you're not getting some php errors (which in production settings will prevent you from seeing anything in response)? See my revised answer with code samples, but, relevant to this comment, suggestion that you make sure that `display_errors` is on.

Comment: The problem is not on the PHP side. It is displaying the query parameters fine *when it receives them*. The problem is the connection from the iPhone is not sending those parameters at all. I am not getting any errors on the server side.

Comment: @chaiguy As you can see from my working example, the problem isn't `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLRequest`, either. Parameters in a URL get passed fine (and lots of us do that all the time). There's got to be something else in the mix (redirects? port numbers?). Have you looked at the `URL` of the `response` object (as well as confirmed that `NSError` was `nil`)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34406/discussion-between-rob-and-chaiguy)

Comment: Ended up figuring it out (see my answer). It was indeed a server-side issue after all. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, [as according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581576/238948), the problem was not with `NSURLConnection` or the phone at all, but with my use of mod-rewrite on the server side. The url parameters were not being explicitly matched and thus were somehow not being interpreted as query parameters by PHP, even though strangely enough they were still part of the url the page saw, as reflected by `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (but not `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`). How Chrome was getting around this I have no idea.

My solution will be to just check `REQUEST_URI` instead of `QUERY_STRING`, instead of worrying about mod-rewrite, which is a serious pain. ;)